# Flask-SQLAlchemy Legacy vs New Query Interface

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to update some queries in a web application because as stated in Flask-SQLAlchemy

```
You may see uses of Model.query or session.query to build queries. That query interface is
considered legacy in SQLAlchemy. Prefer using the session.execute(select(...)) instead.
```

I have a query:

```py
subnets = db.session.query(Subnet).order_by(Subnet.id).all()
```

Which is translated into:

```sql
SELECT subnet.id AS subnet_id, subnet.name AS subnet_name, subnet.network AS subnet_network, subnet.access AS subnet_access, subnet.date_created AS subnet_date_created
FROM subnet ORDER BY subnet.id
```

And I take the `subnets` variable and loop it over in my view in two different locations. And it works.

However, when I try to update my query and use the new SQLAlchemy interface:

```py
subnets = db.session.execute(db.select(Subnet).order_by(Subnet.id)).scalars()
```

I can only loop once and there is nothing left to loop over in the second loop?

How can I achieve the same result with the new query interface?

Comment: I think you mean `db.session.execute(db.select(Subnet).order_by(Subnet.id).scalars().all()`

Comment: @python_user Another question, what is the use of `.scalars()`?

Comment: it is used to return only the "first column" in your select statement, in your case that is `Subnet` table itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments to the question, your second example is not directly comparable to your first example because your second example is missing the `.all()` at the end.

Side note:

```py
session.scalars(select(Subnet).order_by(Subnet.id)).all()
```

is a convenient shorthand for

```py
session.execute(select(Subnet).order_by(Subnet.id)).scalars().all()
```

and is the recommended approach for SQLAlchemy 1.4+.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the 2.0 migration docs for ORM:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_20.html#migration-orm-usage

It lists some examples to show your how to migrate your code from 1.x style to 2.x style. For example:

#### `get()`

1.x:

```
session.query(User).get(42)
```

2.x:

```
session.get(User, 42)
```

#### `all()`

1.x:

```
session.query(User).all()
```

2.x:

```
session.execute(select(User)).scalars().all()
```

#### Note

For Flask-SQLAlchemy, you also need to:

1. Replace `session` with `db.session`.
2. Replace `select` with `db.select` or import the `select` directly from `sqlalchemy`:

```
from sqlalchemy import select
```